# Set numeric column to equal formatted varchar currency column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

I have a VARCHAR(1000) column of prices with dollar signs (e.g. `$100`) and I have created a new `NUMERIC(15,2)` column, which I'd like to set equal to the prices in the VARCHAR column.

This is what worked for me in MySQL:

```
UPDATE  product_table
SET cost = REPLACE(REPLACE(price, '$', ''), ',','');
```

but in PostgreSQL it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  column "cost" is of type numeric but expression is of type character
LINE 2: SET cost = REPLACE(REPLACE(price, '$', ''), ',','');
                   ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I tried to follow the hint and tried some Google searches for examples, but my small brain hasn't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can do this in one swoop, rather than replacing **'$'** and **','** s in separate calls:

```
UPDATE product_table
SET cost = regexp_replace(price, '[$,]', '', 'g')::numeric(15,2);
```

In `regexp_replace` the pattern **[$,]** means to replace either of **'$'** or **','** with the replace string (the empty string **''** in this case), and the **'g'** flag indicates that all such patterns need to be replaced.

Then you need to cast the resulting string to a `numeric(15,2)` value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast the result of `REPLACE` with `cast .. as numeric`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE  product_table
SET cost = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, '$', ''), ',','') AS NUMERIC);
```

I wouldn't suggest having this table structure though, because it can lead to anomalies (`cost` value doesn't reflect the `price` value).